# How to calculate person's age

Tags: java, android

I am trying to develop an Android app through Android Atudio to calculate the age of the person. The app is running with no syntax errors but there is a logical error in the calculations with dates like 12/7/1996, --the number of years and months is wrong.

When I enter the date 1997/6/12 the result is 23 years 11 months and 6 days while the expected result is 24 years 0 months and 6 days.

```
package com.example.helloworldapp;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public void BtnClicked(View BtnView) {
        EditText year = findViewById(R.id.year);
        EditText month = findViewById(R.id.moth);
        EditText day = findViewById(R.id.day);
        TextView result = findViewById(R.id.TV);
        int differanceOfYears = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR) - Integer.parseInt(year.getText().toString());
        int differanceOfMonthes = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MONTH) - Integer.parseInt(month.getText().toString());
        int differanceOfDays = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) - Integer.parseInt(day.getText().toString());
        if (differanceOfDays < 0) {
            differanceOfMonthes = differanceOfMonthes - 1;
            differanceOfDays = 30 + differanceOfDays;
        };
        if (differanceOfMonthes < 0) {
            differanceOfYears = differanceOfYears - 1;
            differanceOfMonthes = 12 + differanceOfMonthes;
        };
        int numberOfDays = differanceOfDays + differanceOfMonthes * 30 + differanceOfYears * 365;
        result.setText("you have lived for " + differanceOfYears + "" + "years, " + differanceOfMonthes + "" + "months and " + differanceOfDays + "" + "days ," + "totally" + numberOfDays + "" + "days");
    }
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

Comment: "There is a logical error" isn't diagnostic. What's actually happening? What's expected to happen?

Comment: when i enter the date  1997/6/12 the result is 23 years 11 months and 6 days while the expected result is 24 years 0 months and 6 days

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check this `System.out.println(Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MONTH))` it prints out `5` even though the current month is June. This is probably because in Calendar it is the Month at index 5 (Starting from 0)

From the docs: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#MONTH

```
public static final int MONTH

Field number for get and set indicating the month. This is a calendar-specific 
value. The first month of the year in the Gregorian and Julian calendars is 
JANUARY which is 0; the last depends on the number of months in a year.
```

Just add 1 to your `differanceOfMonthes`.

Cool program btw!

Comment: firstly thanks for your motivation xD , i have tried your solution (add 1 to difference of months), months worked correctly but in the date 6/7/1997 the result is 23years 0 months and 6 days and the expected result is 24 years

Comment: Are you sure? I was born in July 1996 and I'm still only 23. What year are you living in? xD

Comment: sorry i have entered wrong inputs to the app it works correctly , thanks a lot <3

Answer (score -2):

Try using Date Picker to read date from user in proper format. In editText user can write date in different format. And this article of [geeksforgeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-number-of-days-between-two-given-dates/) may help you understand logic